# MVC 5 Multiple Anti Forgery tokens AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, antiforgerytoken

My issue is that I have a partial view which holds a form full of drop downs. I am using AJAX to dynamically update drop down content. Everything works fine until I implement the Anti Forgery Tokens. Upon serialising my form in the ajax post, I am picking up both the anti forgery token in my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` form and the anti forgery token in the form I am posting data from `_config.cshtml`. This is leading to the validation attribute canning the post and stopping ajax from working.

I have tried the following:

1. Removing all tokens and just placing a single token in the `_Layout.cshtml` page and referring to that in the ajax call. This works for Ajax but upon submitting the form I get a token not found error since the token is not in the form.
2. I then tried posting the form with AJAX too and referring to the single token in the `_Layout.cshtml` view. This returned data to ajax and not an entire view as I was hoping.

My questions are:

1. How can I put only the current forms token into the ajax post function?
2. Alternatively, is there a correct way to do what I am trying to do?

I am pretty certain there is a simple way to sort this out but I am really just a beginner with all this and I am trying to find my feet. Any help would be appreciated.

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
            </li>
            @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            { 
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
            }
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    }
    else
    {
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
            }
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
        </ul>
    }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Doogies Website</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
</head>
<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "_AFT"})) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()}

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Doogies Site", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("RTCG", "RTCG_Configurator", "Rtcg")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content" >
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Chris Duguid</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**_config.cshtml** (partial view where the form resides)

*Yes I am aware the form has no submit information. I am at the point where I was trying out the submitting using ajax.*

```
@model HomeWeb.Models.RtcgConfigurationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm( new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" , id = "configform"}))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h3>Configure RTCG</h3>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgCabinetType, "Cabinet Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgCabinetType, Model.Cabinets, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgCabinetType)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgAdaptorType, "Adaptor Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgAdaptorType, Model.Adaptors, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgAdaptorType)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgQtyAdaptors, "Adaptor Qty.", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgQtyAdaptors, Model.AdaptorQtys, new { onchange = "changed();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgQtyAdaptors)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgTerminationMethod, "Termination", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgTerminationMethod, Model.TerminationMethods)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgTerminationMethod)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgFaceplateStyle, "Faceplate Style", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgFaceplateStyle, Model.FacePlateStyles)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgFaceplateStyle)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgScreenPrinting, "Screenprinting", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgScreenPrinting, Model.ScreenPrintOptions)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgScreenPrinting)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgApplication, "Fibre Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgApplication, Model.Applications)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgApplication)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RtcgVerminProof, "Vermin Proof", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.RtcgVerminProof, Model.VerminProofing)

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RtcgVerminProof)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
                <input  value="Get Quotation" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: none" onclick="submitajax()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changed() {
        var tokensource = $('#_AFT');
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', tokensource).val();
        $.extend(formData, { '__RequestVerificationToken': token });
        $.ajax({
           url: '/Rtcg/Ajax_DropdownChanged',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#config-form').html(result);
            },
        })
    }

    function submitajax() {
        var tokensource = $('#_AFT');
        var formData = $('form').serialize();
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', tokensource).val();
        $.extend(formData, { '__RequestVerificationToken': token });
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Rtcg/updateDB',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {

            },
        })
    }
</script>
```

**RTCG_Configurator** ('index' view presented when body rendered)

```
@model HomeWeb.Models.RtcgConfigurationModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RTCG Configurator";
}

<section >
    <div class="col-md-6 pv" id="config-form">
        @Html.Partial("_config")
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-6" >
    </div> 
</section>
<div style="clear:both">
    <br /><br />
    <p><a href="~/Home/Index" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">&laquo; Back Home </a></p>
</div>
```

**Controller -  Ajax_DropdownChanged()**

```
// POST: handle dropdown changes from Ajax
      [HttpPost]
      [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Ajax_DropdownChanged(RtcgConfigurationModel formData)
        {  
            //handle 'postback' displaying the fields. 
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                RtcgConfigurationModel model = new RtcgConfigurationModel();
                using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    model.Cabinets = DisplayElement.Cabinets(formData);
                    model.Adaptors = DisplayElement.Adaptors(formData);
                    model.AdaptorQtys = DisplayElement.AdaptorQuantities(formData);
                    model.TerminationMethods = DisplayElement.Termination(formData);
                    model.FacePlateStyles = DisplayElement.Faceplates(formData);
                    model.ScreenPrintOptions = DisplayElement.ScreenPrinting(formData);
                    model.Applications = DisplayElement.Application(formData);
                    model.VerminProofing = DisplayElement.VerminProof(formData);   
                }
                return PartialView("_config", model);
                //return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Change `$('form').serialize();` to `$('#xxx').serialize()` where `xxx` is the `id` attribute of the form (so that you only serialize the form you want rather than serializing all forms, and therefore all antiforgery tokens)

Comment: I feel so stupid. It makes sense when someone says it but I have been staring at the screen in a bad case of diminishing returns for the last 2 hours. It works... Thanks a million.

Comment: Well I did tell that in my comments to your last question :) Perhaps I better add an answer this time :)

Comment: Just checked and yes you did, I missed that snippet of info and once again learned the hard and mildly embarrassing way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `var formData = $('form').serialize();` will serialize the values of all form controls in all forms in the view, including the antiforgery tokens, which is why you submitting multiple tokens.

Ensure each form has an `id` attribute, and then to submit only the values (and the token) in the form with `id="configform"`, use

```
var formData = $('#configform').serialize();
```

Note also that you do not need

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', tokensource).val();
$.extend(formData, { '__RequestVerificationToken': token });
```

since `.serialize()` already includes the name/value pair for the token (assuming `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is included between the `<form>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a rookie mistake.

As Stephen said in his response. I was not addressing the form in particular. Adding $('#configform').serialize() did the trick.

I added the token to each form and removed it from the layout page.

Here is my ajax code now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changed() {
        $.ajax({
           url: '/Rtcg/Ajax_DropdownChanged',
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#configform').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#config-form').html(result);
            },
        })
    }
</script>
```

Stephen should be wearing a cape.